# Error message using stargazer() to produce regression table

Tags: r, stargazer

I'm trying to produce a table using stargazer() and this error message keeps popping up:

```r
Error in if (is.na(s)) { : the condition has length > 1
```

This is my code:

```
stargazer(lmtrust3, lmtrust4, lmtrust5, lmtrust6, lmtrust7, lmtrust8, 
          lmtrust9, lmtrust10,
          title = "Trust",
          intercept.top = TRUE,
          intercept.bottom = FALSE,
          covariate.labels = c("BBC Article", "Infographic", 
              "Trust in Social Media News", "Age", 
              "Infographic x Trust in Social Media News"),
          out = "tabletrust3.html")
```

It works when I try the first 6 models but not for the last two.

Comment: remove NAs in `lmtrust9` andor in `lmtrust10`: `lmtrust9 <- na.omit(lmtrust9)`, `lmtrust10 <- na.omit(lmtrust10)` and then try again.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work - it still comes up with the error message.